# How to dimension the length of the barcode in 128 code format?

Tags: zpl

Please help me with the following situation.

Using ZPL script I generated a barcode, Code 128.

My interest is to size it within all length of the label.

The label size is 100mm x 100mm.

As you can see in the image below, the configuration of the label is 100mm by 100mm, and what I want is to be able to lengthen the barcode to the full length that can be scanned.

Thank you very much.

```
^XA

^BY2,2,140
^FO70,620^BC^FD(00)340752131001828751^FS


^PQ1
^XZ
```

[image]

Comment: You don't stretch barcodes as you please. The smallest unit of resolution in the printer is the dot, and you specify the width of the thinnest bar in terms of dots, and the length of the barcode will unambiguously result from that. If you want the barcode to be longer, increase the thinnest bar width in `^BY`. If at width `2` the barcode is too short and at width `3` it's too long, then you have to stick with `2`.

Comment: If you don't like the margins being different sizes, center the barcode.